# \bfseries bolds more than intended

Tags: formatting, bold

Been using the `\bfseries` lately, instead of `\textbf` and those, because I learned that they were deprecated in newer versions.

Anyway, the `\bfseries` bolds the rest of my document, even though I'm using curly braces.

### Example:

```
\bfseries{This is meant to be bolded}
While this is not meant to be bolded, yet still, it is.
```

It works just fine within other environments, like `tabulars` and such. It seems like an `\end` command stops it from bolding more, but if I use it regularly in the document, it just messes it up.

Anyone have any experience with this?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! `\bfseries` is a switching command, i.e., it doesn't take an argument. If you input `{\bfseries This is meant to be bolded}` you'll get what you want. Incidentally, the command `\textbf` is *not* deprecated, though `\bf` is indeed deprecated.

Comment: `\textbf` is *not* deprecated, where have you learned that (we would like to know, such that that information can be fixed). `\bfseries` is a switch. It is in affect until the current group ends. In your case use `\textbf` instead

Comment: See now also David Carlisle’s great answer: [Formatting text inside minipage](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/160517) (the title is misleading).

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Here are some ways to bold a text (and only this text, not the following part of the document):

```
\textbf{Text to bold}
{\bfseries Text to bold}
\bfseries Text to bold \mdseries
```

One can also mention this one but it is not recommended since `bfseries` is not an environment. However it works...

```
\begin{bfseries} Text to bold \end{bfseries}
```

In math-mode, use the `bm` package:

```
\usepackage{bm}
\begin{document}
$\bm{f(x)=0}$
\end{document}
```

Comment: @Aleksander Here you have all the types (in german...): http://de.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX-W%C3%B6rterbuch:_Schriften Left column: switching command; middle column: local command; right column: deprecated command

Comment: I may be wrong, but I think the last one only works by accident, there is no `bfseries` environment.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. I think so too, but the fact is that it works...

Comment: Yeah, but if it isn't intended, I would perhaps not recommend using it. Edit: but then, I may be exaggerating, someone else would have say.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. See my edit (and I agree with you concerning the "use" of this method)

Comment: @TorbjørnT. actually it is by design rather than by accident that commands may be used as environments.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle You would know, bad choice of words on my part. Is there anything 'wrong' with using `\bfseries` and similar as environments though?

Comment: @TorbjørnT. It's not really the best design in latex so your advice not to do it isn't bad, it was just an observation that it was definitely part of the original latex design.`bfseries` is safe enough actually but you have to be careful with say `\begin{small}` to include a `\par` at the end (same is true of `{\small` but somehow it is easier to forget in the environment form), which is why latex offers separate environments like `sloppypar` and `flushleft` instead of using the commands as environments `\begin{sloppy}` `\begin{raggedright}` even though they do work if used with care.