# problem with alignment of an image in the center of the page in lyx

Tags: graphics, floats, horizontal-alignment, lyx

I have this doubt

Using lyx inside a floating I been putting the images, everything was good but then I realized something: some images are aligned in the center and others not. I don't understand because I have put the latex code `\centering` beside every image but it seems that this doesn't work for all the images.

[image]

[image]

Do you know what could be the problem and what can I do?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Are the images it doesn't work for very wide? `\centering` won't help in that case, they'll just poke out on the right anyway. The boring way of fixing it is to insert some negative horizontal space by for example writing `\hspace*{-1cm}` in an ERT just before the image. Another way is to use `\makebox` as in [this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/16584/586) (also with ERTs.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code. Many people here use LaTeX directly, so probably is better if you show the LaTeX code (View menu) or an exported MWE (File menu)  from   `\documentclass{...}` to `\end{document}`.

Comment: use `\frame{\includegraphics{.......}}` the frame will put a visible box around the image so you can see how big latex thinks it is, it may be wider than the page (in which case use [width=\textwidth] to scale it down) or it may have white space _inside_ the frame in which case the specified bounding box for the figure is incorrect.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your replays. I have been trying to control this problem with your advices. The images I'm using are not bigger that the page, actually it seems that the problem is only with the smaller images, like if the Latex code were invisible for the editor. But then I put the image in another lyx file just to prove and.. surprise!! not problem with them in a new project. Does it have any sense?, I mean, in theory the general configuration (margins, tipography...) of the editor should have effect on all the files, or not?

Comment: Could you create a minimal example? That is, remove as much content as you can from your document while still demonstrating the problem, then edit your question to include either the `.lyx` file itself or the exported LaTeX source. (A `.lyx` file is just plain text, so if you open it in a text editor you can just copy everything.)

Answer (score 11):

The captures are from a Lyx in Spanish, but the procedure must be the same in the English version, may be with different words to those that I use.

**LyX method:**

[image: MWE]

1. Select with the cursor select a block of text iside the `figure` float but without text, including just the image (when done, you will see a cyan border around the image)
2. Right mouse click.
3. Select "Paragraph configuration" (or something with this meaning)
4. Select the radio button "Center"
5. Apply or Accept

**ERT method:**

[image: MWE2]

1. Put the cursor just ***before*** the image, but inside of the `figure` float
2. Insert a ERT box (Ctrl+L)
3. Write `\centering`

You will see the image still in the left side but will be centered in the PDF:

Comment: While I applaud you taking the time to write such a detailed answer, this really is just repeating exactly what has been said before. And regarding your final note, I think you're mixing `center` and `centering`. (Sorry if I sound like a grumpy old guy, that is not my intention.)

Comment: One more answer stating the same, now with illustration.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. Lyx 2.0.5.1 write `\begin{centering}`, not `\begin{center}`, in the float. With respect to the answer, yes is the same. I started without see any answer, and I spent time making screenshots, draft and was doing other things too.  I saw the others answers afer saving. That's it. If you want include the screenshots in your answer (or your own images, of course) I will delete this answer.

Comment: Wrt. to `center` vs. `centering`: I know what LyX does. As far as I know there isn't really any `centering` environment though, and it is `center` that adds vertical space, see e.g. http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/23653/586. (It works because LaTeX is created so that commands may work as environments, even if that is not always recommended, see e.g. [this comment](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/131180/bfseries-bolds-more-than-intended/131183#comment295942_131183) by David Carlisle. Oh, and I'm too lazy, so I'll just delete my answer insted.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. You should not delete your answer, please restore it. With respect to `centering` environment, after all, it works, then exists. :-). Well seriously, you're absolutely right. If I remember correctly, long ago Lyx really added this vertical space (so, using `center`), but  usually I write only plain LaTeX using \centering inside floats, hence my confusion.

Comment: There really isn't much point in having two (or three) answers saying the exact same thing, in my opinion, and yours is really better than mine.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. This is very kind of you, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You rarely need to insert TeX directly in LyX documents, and in fact using `\centering` here is inadequate.

For alignment of figures, simply right-click the paragraph where the picture is and select **Paragraph settings...** Choose the alignment and you're done.

Comment: How is it inadequate? (And by the way, I mentioned the paragraph setting in my answer as well.)

Comment: @TorbjørnT.: Sorry, I didn't read your answer entirely. It's inadequate because LyX provides the Paragraph interface that should be used instead. I like to think of TeX insertion in LyX as a hack for problems that can't be handled in the current version. More LyX evolves, less TeX inlines in the document.

Comment: I do sort of agree that if things can be handled (easily) via the LyX GUI, then that is the best way to do it, but I'm not sure 'inadequate' is the right word to use, at least with my understanding of it. Also, LyX adds `centering` as an environment inside figures, which it isn't intended as, AFAIK.