# Formatting text inside minipage

Tags: formatting, minipage

If I use `\begin{textbf}` and `\end{textbf}` (for example) inside a minipage, it seems to apply only to the first character. Here's a simple example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\begin{minipage}{10cm}
\begin{textbf}
This is a test.
\end{textbf}
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

Only the "T" of "This" appears bold. Am I doing something very stupid? (Probably!)

Answer (score 6):

```
\begin{textbf}
This
\end{textbf}
```

is

```
\begingroup\textbf This \endgroup
```

which is

```
\begingroup\textbf{T}his \endgroup
```

So the fact that it only affects the `T` is unrelated to the `minipage`.

You want the declarative version `\bfseries` not the `\textbf` command which takes an argument.

```
\begin{minipage}{3cm}\bfseries
 This
\end{minipage}
```